# Count Sub Total and Total in Dynamic Pivot Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to create a query with a total and sub total in a dynamic pivot.

I have a table with 3 columns:
[image]

How to get result like this?

[image]

This is the query I have, but I can't create total and sub total:

```
DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(item)
from @mytable

DECLARE @SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT name, location, ' + @Columns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT name, location, item
    FROM @mytable

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    count(item)
    for item  IN (' + @Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

I appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this using `ROLLUP` and `GROUPING`

```
DECLARE @Pivot_Columns  AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @select_Columns VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @Pivot_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
SELECT @select_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',Sum(' + Quotename(item) + ') as '+Quotename(item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT case when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 0 then ''Total''+ '' '' + name 
when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 1 then ''Total'' 
else name end Name, location, '
           + @select_Columns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT name, location, item
    FROM #SampleData

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    count(item)
    for item  IN ('
           + @Pivot_Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
group by name,location with rollup 
'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

- **[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/ELUQ33624)**

**Note :** I have made a change in how you are concatenating the rows into comma separated values. You current method of string concatenation isn't guaranteed to work all the time. I have used `For Xml Path('')` method for concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` to calculate `Total item` before `Pivot`

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleData
(
    Name varchar(10),
    Location varchar(20),
    Item varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #SampleData
VALUES
('Ron', 'Loc A', 'Pencil'),
('Ron', 'Loc A', 'Pencil'),
('Ron', 'Loc B', 'Pen'),
('Ron', 'Loc B', 'Laptop'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil'),
('Tom', 'Loc B', 'Pencil'),
('Tom', 'Loc B', 'Pen'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Laptop'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil')


DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(sd.item)
from (select DISTINCT item from #SampleData) sd

DECLARE @SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT name, location, ' + @Columns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT  CASE WHEN sd.Location is null then ''Total '' + sd.Name
             ELSE sd.Name
          END as Name, 
          sd.Name as GroupName,
          sd.Location, sd.item, count(item) AS CountValue
    FROM #SampleData sd
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((sd.Name, sd.Location, sd.item),(sd.Name, sd.item))

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    sum(CountValue)
    for item  IN (' + @Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
Order by GroupName, name
'

EXEC(@SQL)

DROP TABLE #SampleData
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/GTKM34090

Comment: Use [GROUPING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql) instead of `Case` statement.

Comment: The concatenation method used isn't guaranteed to work. Always better to use `xml path()`. Hope you don't mind for saying these suggestions

Comment: Also your result does not bring last Grand Total in last line ;)

Comment: all the query works. I will improved it, thankyou for your helped :)